# como agrego una nueva opción a la sección de Theme template para crear paginas si no quiero utilizar la opción de default page en mi tienda de shopify

Tags: frontend, shopify, liquid

[image: como agrego otra opción al menú de online strore]

ya intente varios métodos pero ninguno me funciona, puesto que si utilizo algunos de esos templates y edito la pagina nueva esta, me cambia la pagina en la  que se baso. ya lo intente como lo dice shopify en sus manuales y no consigo corregir este error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpRW.jpg)

ya intente tutoriales y lo que dice la documentación de shopify